# find summation of data set when mean and standard deviation are given

Tags: probability

[image: question is here]

The mean and standard deviation of a series of data points $(X_1 , X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5, X_6, X_7, X_8)$ are $9.5$ and $\sqrt{23.75}$

Comment: What are your own thoughts? Hint: It's important to know how the mean is calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mean is the sum divided by the number of point, $8$ in this case. Therefore, the sum of the points is $8\times 9.5$.