# Out of $50$ people surveyed in a study, $35$ are smokers, among whom $20$ are males.

Tags: probability

Out of $50$ people surveyed in a study, $35$ are smokers, among whom are $20$ males. What is the probability that if the person surveyed is a smoker, then he is a male?

After trying, I came up with this:

probability of being a smoker $= 35/50$

probability of being a smoker who is male $= 20/50$

probability of being male and smoker $= P(B \mid A) = 20/35$

Comment: Are you saying that $20$ of the $35$ people who smoke are male?

Comment: Between this and [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2741219/find-summation-of-data-set-when-mean-and-standard-deviation-are-given) it looks like you are just posting your homework here for us to do for you.  Please edit to show your efforts and to indicate where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Voting to close the question.  If you can, please edit to show your efforts.

Comment: Your answer is correct.